# Mlt framework: Crashes while playing video

Tags: c++, qt, video, mlt

I'm using MLT framework to create a video player for my app in which users will be able to preform some small video editing for a specific task. I'm also using QT for this app. I have started with essentially the BuildOnMe example which can be found [here](https://github.com/mltframework/BuildOnMe)

The problem is the player crashes on videos after a certain time (always different).

At one point I was printing the number of frames to see if it was on the same number (it isn't) and when it crashed it printed this: `[mlt_pool] out of memory`

Do I need to take care of memory management for mlt?

I'm using QT5.3

My code, in case it helps, can be found [here](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?454622) (I didn't add the .h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was from the Mlt::Frame created in the function `on_frame_show`

This frame needs to be deleted, in the example it is used on the mac openGL class. But on windows since it's never used it'll quickly build up on the memory.